# how to include custom message in email using google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, sendmail

i've written the following function, which is designed to check the status of a webpage, then email the result to defined recipients (`toList`).

```
function testStatusNotif() {
  var url = hostname + "/monitoring";
  var listTo = listGroup;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
  if(response.getResponseCode() !== 200) {
    var message = 'Failed (test): response ' + response.getResponseCode();
    MailApp.sendEmail(listTo, "check the platform is up and operational", message);
  } else {
    var message = 'Passed (test): response ' + response.getResponseCode();
    MailApp.sendEmail(listTo, "trade platform is ready to open", message);
  }
}
```

while this function works as is, i want to separate the `sendMail` steps into their own functions. the key driver is because i want to cater for more scenarios as well as have different recipients and messages for each of the scenarios. i also want to reuse the `sendMail` functions for other tests. however when i separate them out, i get `undefined` in place of `message`.

here's an example of the check that returns `undefined`.

```
function testStatusNotif() {
  var url = hostname + "/monitoring";
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
  if(response.getResponseCode() !== 200) {
    var message = 'Failed (test): response ' + response.getResponseCode();
    failEmail(message);
  } else {
    var message = 'Passed (test): response ' + response.getResponseCode();
    passEmail(message);
  }
  return message;
}

function failEmail() {
  var listTo = listFails;
  MailApp.sendEmail(listTo, "check the platform is up and operational", sampleCheck.message);
}
```

can anyone tell me where i'm going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason of `undefined` is that the value is not accepted at the function of `failEmail`. If you want to give `message` to `failEmail(message)` and `passEmail(message)`, please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
function failEmail() {
  var listTo = listFails;
  MailApp.sendEmail(listTo, "check the platform is up and operational", sampleCheck.message);
}
```

#### To:

```
function failEmail(message) { // Modified
  var listTo = listFails;
  MailApp.sendEmail(listTo, "check the platform is up and operational", message); // Modified
}
```

#### Note:

- About the object of `sampleCheck`, I'm not sure from your script. So I modified to `message`.
- Although I'm not sure about the function of `passEmail(message)`, if the situation is the same with `failEmail(message)`, please modify as the same way.

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: thanks @Tanaike, works a treat. such a small change but oh so crucial.

Comment: re: `sampleCheck` my apologies, that's what the `testStatusNotif` function was originally called. i changed it before posting here hoping it would better describe what i was trying to do, but forgot to update all references.

Comment: @mitch-NZ Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. And also thank you for the additional information. I could understand about it.